# Adding a drop down in rails and do particular action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to rails and this might me be a basic question. I checked on the internet but not able to find a simple example(might be my search is bad).

I need to create a form in my view and based the value selected and button clicking action i need to execute a particular action in my controller. I am able to create a drop down in my view using following lines.

```
= form_tag("/rtes", method: "get") do
 = label_tag(:q, "Get Trip Type:")
 = select_tag(:q, options_for_select({ "a" => "r4d_001", "b" => "r4d_002" })
 <br>
 = button_to( "Get Trip", :action => "rtes", :controller =>:q)
```

where rtes is my controller and i have mapped the value of the drop down values to the corresponding action names that needs to be executed when the button is clicked. This is my controller.

```
class RtesController < ApplicationController
@@client=OptimusRtesServiceModel.new

def index
end


def r4d_001
  result = @@client.r4t_001()
  @driver_username = result.trip.loads[0].driver_details[0].driver_user_name
  @driver_password = result.trip.loads[0].driver_details[0].driver_password
  @trip_id = result.trip.trip_id
  @carrier_username = result.carrier_details.carrier_user_name
  @carrier_password = result.carrier_details.carrier_password
end

def r4d_002
  result = @@client.r4t_002()
  @driver_username = result.trip.loads[0].driver_details[0].driver_user_name
  @driver_password = result.trip.loads[0].driver_details[0].driver_password
  @trip_id = result.trip.trip_id
  @carrier_username = result.carrier_details.carrier_user_name
  @carrier_password = result.carrier_details.carrier_password
end
end
```

Now, if the first option in the drop down is selected and the button is clicked the "r4d_001" action in the controller needs to be executed. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly you are getting now with this code? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, if i run the page and select a option in the drop down and click that button an query has been sent and my application goes back to my home page and the corresponding action is not getting called. I am not sure to how to fix this line, to call the corresponding action => button_to( "Get Trip", :action => "rtes", :controller =>:q)

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: How to do that. Can you show me some examples so that i could try? This is my first project on this.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is not like angular that you are trying to use :q variable to pass the value of selection to the button. You can create a drop-down menu instead of using select field to send them to different action for different option. Still if you want to use select field, then you need javascript to handle the front-end task here.

Comment: Can you give me some links to check for both select / drop down menu options and how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified my code to made it work. The idea is to get use the rails params and execute the corresponding action in my controller using case/when.

My view code:

```
= form_tag({:controller=>"r4d", :action=>"result"}, method: :get) do
 = label_tag(:q, "Trip Type: ")
 = select_tag(:q, options_for_select({"a" => "1", "b" => "2"})
 = submit_tag("GetDetails")
```

My Contoller code:

```
class R4dController < ApplicationController
@@client=ServiceModel.new
def r4d_result

 result = case params[:q]
 when "1"
   @@client.1
 when "2"
   @@client.2
 end

 @value = result.value
end

end
```

By this way, i am able to pass the selected value of the drop down and execute the corresponding thing.